# Take screenshot and send by socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, screenshot

I want to take screenshot from server and send it by socket to client,
in client reciev that and show it(as video)

i try this:

## in Server

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import base64
from io import StringIO,BytesIO
def sendVideo(MySocket):
    print("in sendVideo")
    buffer = BytesIO()
    while True:
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        im.save(buffer, format='PNG')
        b64_str = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
        MySocket.send(b64_str)
```

## in Client

```
import ...
def recievVideo(MySocket):
    while True:
        data = MySocket.recv(2048)
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(data)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(imgdata))
        cv2.imshow("Picture",cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        kk = cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF
```

But do not work correctly(This means that it only sends an image(first frame) and only displays the same image)

i use python v3.7

thank you

Comment: you want to create your own remote desktop? that's not as easy as you think it is

Comment: @ AntiMatterDynamite Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: @usr2564301 I edited my question